# MySQL varchar (255) limitation & Anomaly

Tags: php, mysql, varchar

i have defined a column in my mysql database as :

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE `desc` `desc` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL
```

But when i enter a text from my front end to insert into the table , after the size of column data reaches 233 it **truncates further text added** ie text beyond 233 character is not saved !!

i tried changing size of column to VARCHAR(511) but achieved no success.

i counted the nos of characters using php `strlen()` and it revealed 233 characters

Why is MySQL doing this , and how can i save the text ?

Comment: Run `DESCRIBE my_table`. What does it say about the desc column?

Comment: Could it be a charset problem? Try to add some (latin1) characters to your string and see if 2 characters are still missing.

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis DESCRIBE `my_table` reveals `desc` is varchar(255) and NOT NULL and  such ..

Comment: @Clarence i have 'commas' in my string

Comment: So.. to clear it up, the strings you were saving were actually 255 or more characters in length and you didn't count commas?

Comment: umm as i said i just pasted the entire text (along with commas) in the strlen() of php and it gave me 233 @N.B.

Comment: Hmm...what version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: @user1537158 - Hmm. I might suggest asking this problem on dba.stackexchange.com. Changing the size of the column to 511, by the way, should fail, since the character limit of char/varchar is 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `VARCHAR(250)` **NOT NULL** takes one byte to store the length n, and n bytes to store the actual string. So a column holding a value 'abc' will account for 4 bytes. In a `VARCHAR(250)` NULL, the nullity takes one bit, and a NULL value won't take anything else. A non-null value takes that bit, one byte for length and n bytes for data. Needing a bit here means that several nullable columns share one or more bytes to record their nullity.

Other variable length data types are similar. BLOB and TEXT types of the various sizes may have more than a single byte for length, but otherwise work pretty much the same. Numeric types as well as the fixed-length CHAR types have fixed memory requirements. I think I the CHAR will omit the length byte, as its content is padded with spaces to that fixed length.

**Indices might increase the memory requirements. Multy-byte character sets (including `UTF-8`) might increase the memory requirements, so the above statements will only hold if your table was created for latin1 or similar. So you can deduce that `VARCHAR(250)` don't mean 255 caracters, it will depend on how you encode your strings**

Comment: something more lucid please ?

Comment: Well, this mean that abc in latin1 = varchar(3), but abc another encodage type it could be abc = varchar(5);

Comment: iam using latin1_sweedish_ci @Weacked

Answer (score 1):

Use `mb_strlen()` function to count number of characters, it is multibyte-safe, it appears that you have some special characters in your string, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

It depends of the version of the MySQL server and the settings, but if some string exceed the predefined length during insert or update - then MySQL will automatically truncate the exceeded part of it.

Comment: mb_strlen() gives 233 , nothing diff